# Trailing commas and C++

Tags: c++, c

I have read somewhere that the C++ standard does not allow something like `enum an_enum { a, b, c, };`, while later versions of C (I think from mid-90s) do allow such declarations with trailing commas. If C++ is supposed to have backwards compatibility with C, how come this feature is forbidden? Any special reason?

I also read that such trailing commas are actually good, so that just adds to the confusion.

Comment: Trailing commas are good for the lazy programmer. And [laziness is good](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazinessImpatienceHubris) :)

Comment: Trailing commas as especially good if you have one value per line as it makes all lines similar, very useful for computer (or macro) generated values.

Comment: Easy to auto-generate code by printing `a,` `b,` `c,` in a for loop without needing to somehow handle the last case separately like in `a,` `b,` `c`.

Comment: Also better for diffs on multi-line lists. E.g. a single line diff if you add or remove a value from the list.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

C++03 (which is a fairly minor update of C++98) bases its C compatibility on C89 (also known as C90, depending on whether you're ANSI or ISO). C89 doesn't allow the trailing comma. C99 does allow it. C++11 does allow it (7.2/1 has the grammar for an enum declaration).

In fact C++ isn't entirely backward-compatible even with C89, although this is the kind of thing that if had it been in C89, you'd expect C++ to permit it.

The key advantage to me of the trailing comma is when you write this:

```
enum Channel {
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
};
```

and then later change it to this:

```
enum Channel {
    RED,
    GREEN,
    BLUE,
    ALPHA,
};
```

It's nice that only one line is changed when you `diff` the versions. To get the same effect when there's no trailing comma allowed, you could write:

```
enum Channel {
    RED
   ,GREEN
   ,BLUE
};
```

But (a) that's crazy talk, and (b) it doesn't help in the (admittedly rare) case that you want to add the new value at the beginning.

Comment: There's a school of thought that states: if you can't handle a two-line diff as easily as a one-line diff, you've no business running diffs :-)

Comment: I use the "crazy talk" version , but with the comma at the start of the line and then the tab.  It does cause multi-line diff if you add a new value at the start, but that's relatively rare.

Comment: `,GREEN` looks like a lisp macro replacement... ;-)

Comment: Alas, C++ supports it for struct/class initializer lists `foo = {a,b,c,}` and enums `enum {a,b,c,}`, but not even C++20 supports it yet for class member initializer lists `Foo() : a(42), b(13), c(3.14), {}`. So the language is not as cleanly diffable as it *could* be.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the latest draft for C++0x it looks like you can use trailing commas:

```
enum-specifier:
enum-head { enumerator-list opt}
enum-head { enumerator-list , }

enumerator-list:
enumerator-definition
enumerator-list , enumerator-definition
```

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, the last C standard was in 1999. The last (complete) C++ standard was 98 (2003 was an update). 
After that, not all of C99 is going into C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Trailing comma in enum was introduced in C99 as a feature. It does not exist in C90 nor C++ versions that were based on a pre-C99 baseline.