# Comma after last element in C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays

These two arrays have the same size and elements:

```
  int list[] = {1,2,5,2,5,2,5,2,};
  //                           ^ extra comma 
  int size1 = sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]);
  
  int list2[] = {1,2,5,2,5,2,5,2};
  int size2 = sizeof(list2)/sizeof(list2[0]);

  std::cout << "size1: " << size1 << " size2: " << size2 << "\n"; // size1: 8 size2: 8
```

- So, are they completely the same **?**

Why is that extra comma allowed? I get it can be practical whe you copy-paste arrays like

```
someComplicatedStruct list3[] = 
{ {1,5,3},
  {1,2,9},
  {1,2,6},
  {7,2,3},
//       ^ Is this actually usefull?
};
```

But it seems risky, if it is, why is this allowed?

Comment: What would be the risK?

Comment: Check out [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043372/int-a-1-2-weird-comma-allowed-any-particular-reason) .. long story short, a.) it's part of the standard and allowed by the language, and b.) it makes it slightly easier to add/remove hard-coded array elements.

Comment: @YSC like, I could imagine a warning telling you "Hey, did you forget to add an element?"

Comment: Thanks @txtechhelp I'm checking it

Comment: the reason is the same in other languages: [Trailing commas and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6372650/995714), [Why is a trailing comma in a function call not a syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53672206/995714), [Why are trailing commas allowed in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11597901/995714), [Why does C# allow trailing comma in collection initializers but not in params?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26865030/995714)

Comment: It is basically to maintain uniformity. That you are treating all lines as the same.

Comment: A warning is not a risk. What would be the risk to have that comma?

Comment: @YSC I mean , the risk of forgetting an element

Comment: Putting the comma but forgetting the last element is a pretty uncommon case compared to forgetting both.